# How do you repair or re-install the Edge Updater components (scheduled tasks and services)

Tags: windows, services, scheduled-tasks, microsoft-edge

A user has attempted to remove the "Microsoft Edge Update" application from a Windows 10 PC (1909) (Not Edge but the updater), because the uninstall button was greyed out. The user was an admin of the PC. The actions taken were:

Delete the 2 scheduled tasks

- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskMachineCore
- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskMachineUA

Delete 2 services using SC DELETE

- edgeupdate
- edgeupdatem

Removed the registry path
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Edge Update

In an environment where Edge is used and the updater is needed to function, how can we cleanly bring those items back without bringing over pieces from a working PC?

Actions taken:

- Verified on a test PC that never had Edge installed or the updater, that installing 87.x 64bit MSI, the scheduled tasks, services and uninstall entry are added.

On the target PC:

- uninstalled and re-installed edge using the same 87.x MSI as the test PC, no luck
- ran an MSI repair on the edge installer, no luck
- ran the MSI with the /fa  switches
- variations on the above with reboots included as well as trying with the system account
- Googled for help and found NO ONE ever trying to do this, everyone wants to remove edge or fix edge, found no discussions regarding the updater

Have not tried recreating based on content from a working PC, there must be a clean way of resolving this.

Comment: Try downloading and reinstalling Chromium Edge.  https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10/#:~:text=You%20can%20simply%20download%20a,reinstall%20Edge%20without%20losing%20data.

Comment: You don’t; This user royally screwed up the installation; You **might** be able to fix it by installing the 21H1 enablement package once it’s released.  That will of course require you to first install 2004 or 20H1.  The actions taken were destructive, hopefully, this individual no longer has administrator permissions

Answer (score 0):

if the folder with edge updater exists but the services and tasks are missing,

i have managed to restore the 2 deleted services (edgeupdate and
edgeupdatem) by restoring the registry keys from another copy of windows. i will attach the 2 keys to be saved and merged and after that restart the pc and the 2 deleted services will apear and the update will work automatically

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\edgeupdate]
    "DelayedAutostart"=dword:00000001
    "DependOnService"=hex(7):52,00,50,00,43,00,53,00,53,00,00,00,00,00
    "Description"="Păstrează software-ul Microsoft actualizat. Dacă acest serviciu este dezactivat sau oprit, software-ul Microsoft nu va fi actualizat, ceea ce înseamnă că vulnerabilitățile de securitate ce pot apărea nu pot fi remediate și este posibil ca unele caracteristici să nu funcționeze. Acest serviciu se dezinstalează automat atunci când nu există software Microsoft care îl utilizează."
    "DisplayName"="Microsoft Edge Update Service (edgeupdate)"
    "ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
    "ImagePath"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\EdgeUpdate\\MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe\" /svc"
    "ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
    "Start"=dword:00000002
    "Type"=dword:00000010
    "WOW64"=dword:0000014c
    
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\edgeupdate\TriggerInfo]
    
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\edgeupdate\TriggerInfo\0]
    "Type"=dword:00000014
    "Action"=dword:00000001
    "Guid"=hex:80,1e,f8,5e,64,ca,5b,47,b4,69,48,5d,bc,99,3f,e2
```

and the second

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\edgeupdatem]
"DelayedAutostart"=dword:00000001
"DependOnService"=hex(7):52,00,50,00,43,00,53,00,53,00,00,00,00,00
"Description"="Păstrează software-ul Microsoft actualizat. Dacă acest serviciu este dezactivat sau oprit, software-ul Microsoft nu va fi actualizat, ceea ce înseamnă că vulnerabilitățile de securitate ce pot apărea nu pot fi remediate și este posibil ca unele caracteristici să nu funcționeze. Acest serviciu se dezinstalează automat atunci când nu există software Microsoft care îl utilizează."
"DisplayName"="Microsoft Edge Update Service (edgeupdatem)"
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"ImagePath"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\EdgeUpdate\\MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe\" /medsvc"
"ObjectName"="LocalSystem"
"Start"=dword:00000003
"Type"=dword:00000010
"WOW64"=dword:0000014c

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\edgeupdatem\TriggerInfo]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\edgeupdatem\TriggerInfo\0]
"Type"=dword:00000014
"Action"=dword:00000001
"Guid"=hex:80,1e,f8,5e,64,ca,5b,47,b4,69,48,5d,bc,99,3f,e2
```

the tasks could also be restored by exporting the 2 tasks in the task scheduler from another pc and importing them on the target pc